# Appending rows onto a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, append, row

I'm trying to append a 4x1 row of data onto a matrix in python. The matrix is initialized as empty, and then grows by one row during each iteration of a loop until the process ends. I won't know how many times the matrix will be appended, so initializing the array to a predetermined final size is not an option unfortunately. The issue that I'm finding with np.r_ is that the matrix and list being appended need to be the same size, which is rarely the case. Below is some pseudocode of what I've been working with.

```
    import numpy as np

    dataMatrix = np.empty([4,1])

    def collectData():
            receive data from hardware in the form of a 4x1 list

    while receivingData:
            newData = collectData()
            dataMatrix = np.r_(dataMatrix, newData)
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to go about finding a solution to this issue?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064822/how-to-add-items-into-a-numpy-array

Comment: A common `numpy` approach is to append these values to a list, and turn that into an array when you are all done.  List is better for iterative appending than arrays.

Comment: `np.r_` is a fancy front end to 1d concatenate.  It's most useful for stringing together a mixed bag of ranges and linspace, expressed as slices.

Answer (score 0):

As @hpaulj suggested you should use a list of lists and then convert to a NumPy matrix at the end. This  will be **[at least 2x faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29839350/numpy-append-vs-python-append)** than building up the matrix using np.r_ or other NumPy methods

```
import numpy as np

dataMatrix = []

def collectData():
        return 4x1 list

while receivingData:
        dataMatrix.append(collectData())

dataMatrix = np.array(dataMatrix)
```

As a sidenote, with [np.r_](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) the only requirement is that the first dimension of the matrix be equal to the first (and only, in your case) dimension of the array. Perhaps you used np.r_ when you should have used np.c_