# Python - Swap rows and columns, while creating a dictionary with it

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I´m kind of new to Python, and I am trying to convert a list comprehension (Hands-on Data Analysis with Pandas by S.Molin) into a "normal" for loop, just for the mere purpose of practising.

Initially, the data comes from a CSV file and is loaded using Numpy. The result is each CSV row as a single array (void type) as follows:

> *array([('2018-10-13 11:10:23.560', '262km NW of Ozernovskiy, Russia', 'mww', 6.7, 'green', 1), ('2018-10-13 04:34:15.580', '25km E of
> Bitung, Indonesia', 'mww', 5.2, 'green', 0), ('2018-10-13
> 00:13:46.220', '42km WNW of Sola, Vanuatu', 'mww', 5.7, 'green', 0),
> ('2018-10-12 21:09:49.240', '13km E of Nueva Concepcion, Guatemala',
> 'mww', 5.7, 'green', 0), ('2018-10-12 02:52:03.620', '128km SE of
> Kimbe, Papua New Guinea', 'mww', 5.6, 'green', 1)], dtype=[('time',
> '<U23'), ('place', '<U37'), ('magType', '<U3'), ('mag', '<f8'),
> ('alert', '<U5'), ('tsunami', '<i4')])*

What I am trying is to alter it so that I get each column as an array of values, whose keys are the name of the columns:

> *{'time': array(['2018-10-13 11:10:23.560', '2018-10-13 04:34:15.580','2018-10-13 00:13:46.220', '2018-10-12 21:09:49.240',
> '2018-10-12 02:52:03.620'], dtype='<U23'), 'place': array(['262km NW
> of Ozernovskiy, Russia', '25km E of Bitung, Indonesia',  '42km WNW of
> Sola, Vanuatu','13km E of Nueva Concepcion, Guatemala','128km SE of
> Kimbe, Papua New Guinea'], dtype='<U37'),  'magType': array(['mww',
> 'mww', 'mww', 'mww', 'mww'], dtype='<U3'),  'mag': array([6.7, 5.2,
> 5.7, 5.7, 5.6]),  'alert': array(['green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green'], dtype='<U5'),  'tsunami': array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1])}*

The List comprehension used for this purpose is:

```
array_dict = {col: np.array([row[i] for row in data]) for i, col in enumerate(data.dtype.names)}
```

The solution I got so far is:

```
d ={}
for i,col in enumerate(data.dtype.names):
    for row in data:
        d[col].append(row[i])
```

I get the following error:

```
*---------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [51], in <cell line: 2>()
      2 for i,col in enumerate(data.dtype.names):
      3     for row in data:
----> 4         d[col].append(row[i])
KeyError: 'time'*
```

I have researched a bit online and it could be related to the data type column "time". My guess, but I am pretty sure I am wrong, is that in the list comprehension each column is created as NumPy array directly, whereas here I am not setting it to be as such beforehand (and hence the problem with the data type).

Any help would be highly appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To produce the same result as the dictionary comprehension that you've provided:

```py
d = {}
for i, col in enumerate(data.dtype.names):
    values = []
    for row in data:
        values.append(row[i])
    d[col] = np.array(values)
```

The error that you're getting is due to the fact that your dictionary `d` is empty (you have created it like so: `d = {}`. It does not contain the key 'time'. You could create the key like this: `d['time'] = some_value`, but you can't just access it if it doesn't exist.

If you want, you can use the [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). With it, you don't have to create the keys. If you access non-existend keys, the default value will be returned.

With your original code it would look like this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for i, col in enumerate(data.dtype.names):
    for row in data:
        d[col].append(row[i])

dict(d)
```

Then however, the values of your dictionary are not `np.ndaray`s, but simple lists.

Comment: Excellent! I did not think of creating and intermediate list and then converting it to an array-type object.

I guess there is not way to do it in one step?

Many thanks!

Comment: @JaviCV, added some explanation

Comment: @JaviCV, appending to `np.ndarray`s is [NOT good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29840311/14627505). If you want to append an element one by one, use simple lists, and then convert to `np.ndarray`.

Answer (score 1):

A better way of displaying your array is (in `ipython`):

```
In [29]: x
Out[29]: 
array([('2018-10-13 11:10:23.560', '262km NW of Ozernovskiy, Russia', 'mww', 6.7, 'green', 1),
       ('2018-10-13 04:34:15.580', '25km E of Bitung, Indonesia', 'mww', 5.2, 'green', 0),
       ('2018-10-13 00:13:46.220', '42km WNW of Sola, Vanuatu', 'mww', 5.7, 'green', 0),
       ('2018-10-12 21:09:49.240', '13km E of Nueva Concepcion, Guatemala', 'mww', 5.7, 'green', 0),
       ('2018-10-12 02:52:03.620', '128km SE of Kimbe, Papua New Guinea', 'mww', 5.6, 'green', 1)],
      dtype=[('time', '<U23'), ('place', '<U37'), ('magType', '<U3'), ('mag', '<f8'), ('alert', '<U5'), ('tsunami', '<i4')])
In [30]: x.dtype
Out[30]: dtype([('time', '<U23'), ('place', '<U37'), ('magType', '<U3'), ('mag', '<f8'), ('alert', '<U5'), ('tsunami', '<i4')])
In [31]: x.shape
Out[31]: (5,)
```

It highlights the fact you have a structured array with 5 elements, and 6 fields (a compound dtype).

You can create a dict of all fields with:

```
In [32]: adict = {}
    ...: for i in x.dtype.names:
    ...:     adict[i] = x[i]
    ...: 
In [33]: adict
Out[33]: 
{'time': array(['2018-10-13 11:10:23.560', '2018-10-13 04:34:15.580',
        '2018-10-13 00:13:46.220', '2018-10-12 21:09:49.240',
        '2018-10-12 02:52:03.620'], dtype='<U23'),
 'place': array(['262km NW of Ozernovskiy, Russia', '25km E of Bitung, Indonesia',
        '42km WNW of Sola, Vanuatu',
        '13km E of Nueva Concepcion, Guatemala',
        '128km SE of Kimbe, Papua New Guinea'], dtype='<U37'),
 'magType': array(['mww', 'mww', 'mww', 'mww', 'mww'], dtype='<U3'),
 'mag': array([6.7, 5.2, 5.7, 5.7, 5.6]),
 'alert': array(['green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green'], dtype='<U5'),
 'tsunami': array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int32)}
```

`x['time']` is the `time` field for all records.  No need to iterate on records.

This structured array is not 2d; it is 1d, with records and fields (rows and columns is a common way of describing a 2d numeric array, though the terms are technically part of the numpy description.)

```
In [37]: x['mag']
Out[37]: array([6.7, 5.2, 5.7, 5.7, 5.6])
```